# How should I properly create a Ripple Paper Wallet using Ripple-lib or an official api?

Tags: ripple

I'm trying to create a paper wallet using the official Ripple Api, ripple-lib.

The generateAddress() accepts some parameters.

```
'use strict';
const RippleAPI = require('ripple-lib').RippleAPI;

const api = new RippleAPI({
  server: 'wss://s1.ripple.com' // Public rippled server
});
api.connect().then(() => {
  return api.generateAddress();
}).then(info => {
  console.log(info);
  console.log('getAccountInfo done');

  /* end custom code -------------------------------------- */
}).then(() => {
  return api.disconnect();
}).then(() => {
  console.log('done and disconnected.');
}).catch(console.error);
```

This code actually creates a Secret key and an "Address".

```
{
  secret: 'sheWb..................HRyLhk',
  address: 'rNLJ.......................qu3nbb'
}
```

Ok. Now I have my account created. And If I fund it with the 20XRP Reserve it would become an active Ripple account. Yay !

But I don't understand:

- Which is or How can I obtain my Public Key ?
- Which is or How can I obtain my Master Public Key ?
- The generateAddress() methods accepts three parameters. Described here: https://ripple.com/build/rippleapi/#generateaddress But I don't have a clue on how to write those parameters. I'm interested on this because I think that in the first parameter, the "options" object is where I could define the passphrase for the secret key. Maybe I'm wrong.

May anyone sheed some light to these concerns ?

**EDIT:**
I think now that the options object passed to `generateAddress()` is the same options parameter passed to the constructor `RippleApi()` described here https://ripple.com/build/rippleapi/#parameters May anyone confirm this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For paper wallet what you need is only **address**(public) and **secret**(private):

https://github.com/Bithomp/xrp-paper-wallet

Actually, only **secret** would be enough, as you can get an **address** from the **secret**.

https://github.com/Bithomp/bithomp-tools

In Ripple you not have to use a new account for each new order/user. For each new transaction you can use a **destination tag**. That's how you can identify customer/order. Ripple also supports a key rotation, so if **master key** got exposed you can disable it and use a **regular key**. In best practices you assign a **regular key** and use it to sign transactions online, and master key always offline. If a regular key got exposed, you can replace it with a new regular key.

In ripple you can sign transactions with a **keypair** (public key + private key), or with the **secret**.

you can get keypairs for ripple here https://iancoleman.io/bip39/

ripple-lib's `generateAddress()` gives you:

1) a ripple **address** (your public address) starts with `r`

you can share it, it can be used to send you payments.
You can search for the public address in the explorer.

for example: https://bithomp.com/explorer/r9fVvKgMMPkBHQ3n28sifxi22zKphwkf8u

2) a **secret** - a **master key**, which will be used to sign transactions.

3) You can also assign a **regular key** (https://developers.ripple.com/assign-a-regular-key-pair.html)

Options has only two parameters:

- **algorithm** string, The digital signature algorithm to generate an address for. Can be ecdsa-secp256k1 (default) or ed25519.
- **entropy**   array\integer, The entropy to use to generate the seed.

hope it helps..

Answer (score 1):

> The generateAddress() methods accepts three parameters. Described
>   here: https://ripple.com/build/rippleapi/#generateaddress But I don't
>   have a clue on how to write those parameters. I'm interested on this
>   because I think that in the first parameter, the "options" object is
>   where I could define the passphrase for the secret key. Maybe I'm
>   wrong.

Here's some javascript code to demonstrate the input of entropy into the **generateAddress** method.

```
// This functions works on modern browswers, not sure about Node.js. Try https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-sha512 or https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html
async function fun_SHA512_array(entropy) {
    'use strict';

    // Turns a string into an array of integers.
    // Made possible by https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/digest

    const msgUint8 = new TextEncoder().encode(entropy);                           // encode as (utf-8) Uint8Array
    const hashBuffer = await crypto.subtle.digest('SHA-512', msgUint8);           // hash the message
    const hashArray = Array.from(new Uint8Array(hashBuffer));                     // convert buffer to byte array
    // const hashHex = hashArray.map(b => b.toString(16).padStart(2, '0')).join(''); // convert bytes to hex string

    return hashArray;
}

const str_entropy = "Use a cryptographically strong, randomly created string of characters here.";
// Or, your passphrase string would go here.
// Or, you could use a BIP39 Mnemonic but you'd have to remember how you constructed the string. e.g. Did you separate the words with a comma or with a space?
// Or, on the linux terminal you can use: openssl rand -base64 n
// Where n = the number of characters you wish to randomly generate. Which are then converted to base64, therefore the amount of characters ends up being more than n.

var array_sha512 = [];

fun_SHA512_array(str_entropy).then(array_sha512 => {
    var obj_new_account = api.generateAddress({"entropy": array_sha512});
    var str_secret = obj_new_account.secret;
    var str_public_address = obj_new_account.address;

    console.log(str_secret);
    console.log(str_public_address);
});
```

Remember, the entropy is like a seed and will always generate the same **secret** and **address**.